# How do I install selenium without pip?

Tags: python, selenium, cmd, pip, package

I need to install a package, Selenium, for python, but when I run ’pip install selenium’ in my command prompt, it says that ’ pip is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file’. I have added my pip path to PATH  variables, and I have made sure that pip is installed properly. I have reinstalled python to make sure that pip is installed, and repaired python in case there were missing components or something. I have tried running ’py -m pip install selenium’, and it says that selenium is already installed, but when I run my code it says that there is no module named selenium. I have two different python programs, this python and Anaconda;Spyder. When I install selenium on Spyder, it works, but when I run the code it doesn’t work, not showing any errors.  Can you help me

Answer (score 1):

Do you maybe have multiple python versions on your system like for example python2.7 and python3.8?
Maybe you could try using

```
pip3 install ...
python3 -m install ...
python -m pip install ...
```

That worked for me. Could you also share your error.

Comment: Always prefer the surefire explicit way `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip somecommand`. Everything else, might work but there's no guarantee since obviously there's something wrong with OP's setup (maybe the `PATH` is messed up, or anything lie that).

Comment: I have one python verion installed, and I have tried those, but it does not work.  Thanks for your help though!

Comment: Do you get some error messages or what happens, when you type what in ?

Comment: I get an error saying there is no module named selenium, but I have ran a command, py -m pip install selenium in cmd.

Comment: Okay, could you try python -m not py -m and could you also please copy your error in your question

Comment: Maybe this could help, the manual way to install it https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/54783/how-to-manually-install-a-pypi-module-without-pip-easy-install

Answer (score -1):

Are you using macOS?

I ran into a similar issue a while back, try:

`pip3 install selenium`

Comment: No, sorry I am using Windows but thanks for your help!